# Redirection to english version if browser language is not russian

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, redirect

I want to redirect users who has not russian browser using php or js.

My code looks like this but is not working:

```
<?php
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
if ($locale != "ru_RU"){
header('Location: https://www.site/en/');
die();
}
?>
```

If I write `echo $locale` it will write `ru_RU` BUT only in browser where i logged in admin panel (In common browser it won't show anything). How can I make it work globally?

I had also this function with JS but I don't know what to write after this:

```
<script>
let uri = window.location;
let lang = window.navigator.language;
if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
    if (lang != 'ru-RU'){
    /*redirect to "/en/"      */
}
}
</script>
```

Function shouln't affect load speed of page. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You can use `window.location.href = "https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/";` to redirect in JavaScript.

Comment: @nilsf I want to redirect all pages, not only main. If i put this code instead of `/*redirect to "/en/"      */`, It's just keeping redirecting for english browsers.

Comment: You could try checking if the user is in the en/ directory and if not redirecting. All your links in the english version should also point to the english version, so you have to run the code not every time a user clicks on a link.

Comment: @nilsf How can I do this? Can you give me a link to an example, please? I didn't find anything in the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Navigator language Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp) to get the user's browser language and if not 'ru-RU' get the current page path using [Window Location Pathname](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) and redirect to your domain + /en + page path.

```
// Get browser language
var navLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
// Check if it is Russian
if (navLang != 'ru-RU'){
    // Get the page path
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    // Redirect to an English page with the full path
    window.location.href = "/en" + path;
}
```